What's the mechanism by which DHT affects hair pigmentation?
Is it based only in receptors, or is there more to it? How is it possible that under certain conditions terminal hair can grow without pigment?

Can you please not use abbreviations without introducing them?

And please expand your question making it independent of the title, and clarify: a mechanism “based in receptors” means nothing to me.
